# Is it better to cast to a (Float) or declare a new Float when filling a map in a loop?

Tags: java

Which version of the loop would be more efficient? Or does it really not matter?

```
SortedMap<Float,Float> map = uDataMaster.getMap();
for (int i = 0; i < mzNumbers.length; i++) {
    map.put((Float)mzNumbers[i].floatValue(),(Float)intNumbers[i].floatValue());
}
```

versus

```
SortedMap<Float,Float> map = uDataMaster.getMap();
for (int i = 0; i < mzNumbers.length; i++) {
    map.put( new Float(mzNumbers[i].floatValue()),new Float(intNumbers[i].floatValue()));
}
```

Comment: what would be the max size of mzNumbers at any point of time ,anything less than 500 , not requires premature optimization.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Float as it has only 6 digits of accuracy.  Perhaps Double is better (15 digits). You could try TDoubleDoubleHashMap which uses primitive `double` instead of creating objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example will only work due to the auto-boxing introduced with Java 5.  (But you're already using other Java 5 features here, such as Generics, so there's no benefit to avoid this.)  Other than that, they should really be the same.  The compiler is most likely converting this to `new Float(...)` at compile time anyway.

I was going to suggest `Float.valueOf(...)`, but internally, this just calls `new Float(...)`.  However, per the Javadoc and shakedown's suggestion in the comment, this should be the preferred method - even if the current versions of Java aren't actually doing any pooling in their current implementations.

Comment: [`Float.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(float)) is preferred over `new Float` as the `Float` objects _can_ be pooled to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Shakedown - agreed.  That was going to be my original suggestion, until I looked at the method and saw it wasn't doing any pooling - but you're completely correct per the Javadoc.

Comment: Float.valueOf doesn't do any caching.@user1084907 : why are u using float, try double u will never have rounding issues.

Comment: mzNumbers is declared as Number[] mzNumbers, intNumbers is the same.  Both of these arrays are intermediates in the conversion of binary data arrays.  The converter method returns Number[] as the type, and I want to put these into <Float,Float> maps.  They can be very large, so I wanted to save as much time as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll use Float.valueOf(..)